# How To Make Dynamic if-else Condition Inside Flutter TextFormField Validator

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a registration form with some fields and 1 submit button.

I created the UI of the form by separating it into a widget named `custom_text_form_field.dart` because the structure is all the same, only some widgets are dynamic to change, so I can use it multiple times

Following the [original tutorial straight from Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation), the validation works fine as it should, but the problem is that the implemented logic is applied to all the fields in the form - which I don't want that.

I want, for example like this

```
validator: (value) {
  if (forms == "name") {
    if (max > 32 && value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Enter valid value on Name';
    }
  } else if (forms == "email") {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Enter valid value on Email';
    }
  } else if (forms == "phone") {
    if (max > 12 || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Enter valid value on Phone';
    }
  }
}
```

How to pass dynamic if-else logic into Widgets parameter?
Is this possible?
Or should I not use a separate form widget?

Here's my code:
**custom_text_form_field.dart**

```
part of 'widgets.dart';

class CustomTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String hintText;
  final TextInputType type;
  final bool obscureText;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  const CustomTextFormField({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.type,
    required this.hintText,
    this.obscureText = false,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            title,
            style: blackTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: semiBold,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          TextFormField(
            cursorColor: kBlackColor,
            keyboardType: type,
            obscureText: obscureText,
            controller: controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: hintText,
              hintStyle: greyTextStyle,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  defaultRadius,
                ),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  defaultRadius,
                ),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**signup_page.dart**

```
part of 'pages.dart';

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  SignUp({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignUp> createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  final TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController(text: '');

  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController(text: '');

  final TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController(text: '');

  final TextEditingController passwordController =
      TextEditingController(text: '');
    
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppBar header() {
      return AppBar(
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Sign Up',
          style: whiteTextStyle,
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget body() {
      return SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(margin16),
          children: [
            CustomTextFormField(
              title: "Name",
              type: TextInputType.name,
              hintText: 'Your full name',
              controller: phoneController,
            ),
            CustomTextFormField(
              title: "E-Mail",
              type: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              hintText: 'Your e-mail address',
              controller: emailController,
            ),
            CustomTextFormField(
              title: "Mobile Number",
              type: TextInputType.phone,
              hintText: 'Your mobile number',
              controller: phoneController,
            ),
            CustomButton(
              title: 'Sign Up',
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32),
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(content: Text('True')),
                  );
                } else {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("False")));
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
        appBar: header(),
        body: body(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you, please help or advice..

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check and try it out, seems good to implement, fits to my case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define one more property in customtextformfield as `FormFieldValidator<String>? validator` and pass dynamic validator to all the textfields.
modify your **custom_text_form_field.dart** like this.

```
part of 'widgets.dart';

class CustomTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String hintText;
  final TextInputType type;
  final bool obscureText;
  final TextEditingController controller;
FormFieldValidator<String>? validator;

  const CustomTextFormField({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.type,
    required this.hintText,
    this.obscureText = false,
    required this.controller,
this.validator,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            title,
            style: blackTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: semiBold,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          TextFormField(
            cursorColor: kBlackColor,
            keyboardType: type,
            obscureText: obscureText,
            controller: controller,
            validator:validator,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: hintText,
              hintStyle: greyTextStyle,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  defaultRadius,
                ),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  defaultRadius,
                ),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            validator: validator,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and then pass validators for every textfield individually like this.

```
CustomTextFormField(
              title: "Mobile Number",
              type: TextInputType.phone,
              hintText: 'Your mobile number',
              controller: phoneController,
              validator: (value) {
  if (forms == "name") {
    if (max > 32 && value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Enter valid value on Name';
    }
  } else if (forms == "email") {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Enter valid value on Email';
    }
  } else if (forms == "phone") {
    if (max > 12 || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Enter valid value on Phone';
    }
  }
}
            ),
```

Comment: Um, it says "_Can't define a const constructor for a class with non-final fields._" When i add the `FormFieldValidator<String>? validator` fields . Should i add `final`? Is it ok?

Comment: remove this const from const CustomTextFormField({

Comment: Alright, the error now is gone, thanks.. Im trying to implement the code..

Comment: also please mark answer as verified so others can find it useful.

Comment: Of course, i'll mark it accepted because it solves the problem! Even i'll do more if i can.. Many thanks to you, you saved my day as a beginner hehe :D

Comment: If you can, please remove the validator: (value) {} in your answer, i belive it should be deleted..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248590/discussion-between-manish-dayma-and-muhammad-faisal).